# Fcitx "Extra key for trigger input method" changes back to default after restart

Tags: configuration, input-method, fcitx

Using Ubuntu 15.10. Configuring input using the **Input Method Configuration** screen. Whenever I change **Extra key for trigger input method** it works for only that session. Once I restart the computer it goes back to the default value of **SHIFT Both** which is annoying.

Is there a config file that is being overwritten every time I boot up? How can I prevent this?

Comment: So you're just running the normal flavour of Ubuntu? And how exactly are you accessing the settings you speak of?

Comment: thanks and I solved this problem now ,you can use: fcitx-configtool to get this settings

Comment: If you have found the solution please post it as an answer to help others in the future.

Comment: Yes I'm going to post the solution tomorrow, it's pretty late in China now, so I will post it tomorrow morning.

Comment: Right, yes, of course, I understand.

Comment: It sounds as if you don't use the tools intended for the purpose on Ubuntu 15.10. Have you checked out _System Settings -> Text Entry_?

Answer (score 4):

First you can use this command `fcitx-configtool` to open the fcitx config window,then you can change **Extra key for trigger input method** to whatever you want.

Then you can `cd` into the `fcitx` config folder: `cd ~/.config/fcitx` and  use `chmod 444 profile` to change the permission of the profile to read only, so that no one can change back to default value.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, until I realized that I was using Sougou Pinyin on top of `fcitx`. In the settings of Sougou Pinyin, there is a hotkey (the default is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>) for switching between Chinese and English. I believe it overwrites the settings of `fcitx`. I changed the hotkey to **none** and now the settings of `fcitx` are kept. If you are using Sougou Pinyin as I do, that might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is better than setting 400 for the config file.

Answer (score 1):

@LarryYang 's solution didn't work for me, when I restarted my laptop, it seemed that a new profile was created and replaced the old one even after `chmod +444 profile` is used.

After some experiment I'm sure it is a behavior introduced by sogou pinyin instead of fcitx. Uninstalling sogou pinyin using `sudo apt-get purge sogoupinyin` saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

@Larry Yang's answer did not help me either. `~/.config/fcitx/profile` seems to re-create and replace itself on each login.

Instead, edit `~/.config/fcitx/config`

Change `SwitchKey=SHIFT Both` to `SwitchKey=Disabled` or whatever you like.

After saving and exiting, use `chmod 400 config` to make the configuration persist between logins.

Answer (score 0):

Changing permission of the config file works for me.

- disable switchKey via `fcitx-configtool`
- run `chmod 400 ~/.config/fcitx/config`

Comment: Seems to be pretty much the same as [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/752584/527764)?

Comment: Is this a "thanks worked for me too" comment to the link @Zanna posted?